# keep getting "cannot be inferred" error when trying to call my htmlhelper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and Framework 4.5.
My Index.view calls this partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyCategories", Model)
```

my model is referenced in the partial view:

```
@using MyApp.ModelHelpers
@model MyApp.Models.MyViewModel
```

In the partial view I am trying to call htmlHelpers class inside a loop in the model:

```
@Html.SpecialTextBoxFor(Model.Category[i].Name)
```

and in the htmlHelpers class I have this method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SpecialTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```

When I try to call my htmlhelper from the partial view using this:

```
@Html.SpecialTextBoxFor(Model.Category[i].Name)
```

I get this error: 
The type arguments for method 'MyApp.HtmlHelpers.SpecialTextBoxFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I have tried

```
@Html.SpecialTextBoxFor(m => m.Category[i].Name)
```

after the dot, it can't find the Category

in my web.config I have the proper setting:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

I tried resetting it to 4.5.1 according to some post, but no change.

I verified that I have the correct reference to my namespace in the views web.config:

```
<add namespace="MyApp" />
```

and that I also have in my global.asax.cs

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

What else should I try!?

Comment: Try changing the deceleration to: this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,

Comment: that worked, post it as answer and I will mark it. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your declaration of the extension function to:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SpecialTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```